# Why $(\mathbb F_2 [x] / (x^3 + x +1))^×$ has order 7?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, cyclic-groups

My professor said that $(\mathbb F_2 [x] / (x^3 + x +1))^×$ has order 7, I am wondering, why this is true?

And what is the structure of this group? Is it a cyclic group?

Could someone clarify this to me, please?

Comment: Do you know how many elements $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3 + x + 1)$ has? Can you think of an element here that cannot be a unit? As to whether it's cyclic, there aren't that many groups of order $7$.

Comment: @ronno for your first question, no I do not, can you clarify please how we can know the number of elements of this group?

Comment: Cosets of the ideal $(x^3 + x + 1)$ are uniquely represented by polynomials of degree $\le 2$ (why?)

Answer (score 3):

Polynomial $q(x)=x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$.  Because if it was reducible, then it could be factored like $(x+c)\cdot p_2(x)$ where $p_2$ is a polynomial of degree 2.

Now if $q$ had a factor of degree 1, then $q(0)=0$ or $q(1)=0$ because the only linear factors over $\Bbb F_2[x]$ are $x$ or $x+1$; but $q(0)=q(1)=1$.

Hence, $\Bbb F_2[x]/q(x)$ has order 8 and is a (finite) field, and therefore all elements except 0 are units:

$$(\Bbb F_2[x]/q(x))^\times = \Bbb F_2[x]/q(x)\setminus\{0\}$$

Because the order of the multiplicative group is $8-1=7$ which is a prime, it must be a cyclic group, and indeed one finds that $x$ generates $(\Bbb F_2[x]/q(x))^\times$:

$$\begin{align}
x^1 &= x \\
x^2 &= x^2 \\
x^3 &= x+1 \\
x^4 &= x\cdot x^3 = x(x+1) = x^2 + x \\
x^5 &= x\cdot x^4 = x^3+x^2 = x^2+x+1 \\
x^6 &= (x^3)^2 = (x+1)^2 = x^2+1\\
x^7 &= x\cdot x^6 = x^3+x = 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why it has order 8? I did not get that

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x^3+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. Indeed, it has degree $3$, so to check irreducibility, one needs to show that the polynomial has no zero in $\mathbb{F}_{2}=\{0, 1\}$ which is easy to verify. Now, there is a general result which says that a quotient ring of the form
$$
F[x]/(p(x))
$$
is a field whenever $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over a field $F$. Therefore,
$$
E = \mathbb{F}_{2}[x]/(x^3+x+1)
$$
is a field. By definition, every non-zero element in $E$ is (multiplicatively) invertible. This means that the group of nonzero elements
$$
E^{\times} = E - \{0\}
$$
has exactly $7$ elements. As @ronno points out in the comments, there are not too many groups of order $7$ (because $7$ is prime). Can you see which group is it?

Comment: Why this has order 8? You did not clarify the details of this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/542210/746312 for example.